# Change the color of rule in moderncv

Tags: moderncv

I have a question about `moderncv`. I want to work with the `moderncv` style `casual` and would like to change the color of the rule in the `cvtitle` which is defined by

```
{\color{color2!50}\rule{\textwidth}{.25ex}}
```

I defined a color by `\definecolor{dagr}{rgb}{0.35,0.35,0.35}`
and would like to use this color instead of `color2!50`. How can I do that?

Comment: I suppose `\color{dagr}\rule{\textwidth}{.25ex}}` should work.

Answer (score 2):

You can patch `\makecvtitle` and change the color:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{casual}
\moderncvcolor{blue}
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\definecolor{dagr}{rgb}{0.35,0.35,0.35}
\patchcmd{\makecvtitle}
  {\color{color2!50}\rule{\textwidth}{.25ex}}
  {\color{dagr}\rule{\textwidth}{.25ex}}
  {}
  {}

\name{John}{Doe}
\title{Title}
\address{street and number}{postcode city}{country}
\phone[mobile]{+1~(234)~567~890}

\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\section{Education}
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}  % 

\end{document}
```

[image]